# Reproduce the /etc/shadow passwords

Tags: authentication, md5

I am trying to manually reproduce a /etc/shadow password hash from the plaintext password and the salt. Let's take as an example the following shadow entry:

```
user:$1$/M$5GK8.h6z8o0WQLEOWC.YI/:16764:0:99999:7:::
```

the plaintext password here is "toor".
I tried appending (and prepending) the salt to the password and hashin it using MD5, but I don't get the same result as in the password file, is there any other transformations the system performs on the plaintext to deduce the hash?
the command I used to generate the hash:

```
echo -n "/Mtoor"| md5sum
```

something else I noticed, the hash saved in the file maps to 176 bits, whereas the traditional md5 maps to 128 bits.

Comment: It's not hashed using MD5, but [MD5Crypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28C%29#MD5-based_scheme).

Answer (score 0):

As @otus noted, the hashes aren't raw MD5 – crypt() uses **MD5Crypt**, which involves [a few dozen MD5 iterations](https://github.com/atheme/charybdis/blob/master/libratbox/src/crypt.c#L1069-L1178) (the exact amount actually differs based on the hash itself), some bitshifting, and some pixie dust.

> `/* Then just as many characters of the MD5(pw,salt,pw) */`

> `/* On a 60 Mhz Pentium this takes 34 msec */`

> `/* Then something really weird... */`

In short, it's not something you can reproduce using basic `md5sum`, but rather by calling the libc [crypt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) function, or using tools such as `mkpasswd` which do the same:

```
# echo -n toor | openssl passwd -stdin -1 -salt /M
$1$/M$5GK8.h6z8o0WQLEOWC.YI/
```

Also, both the salt and hash in the crypt() output are encoded using a slightly-modified **Base64** (6 bits per byte), while `md5sum` prints the hash in hex (4 bits per byte), so that accounts for the difference in output length.